# How to resume normal iPhone volume after notification causes volume to get stuck in lower volume mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, music, notifications, sound-volume

iPhone 4, iOS 5.0.1

Strange problem I've had for a few months.  Sometimes when a notification causes the iPhone to temporarily lower the volume, the volume gets "stuck in quiet mode" and doesn't resume full volume.  As a result, music playback is approximately 25% quieter than normal.  Sometimes getting a subsequent notification is enough to kick back to full volume.

This is very annoying because I never know when the phone is going to ramp up the volume suddenly (if I get a text message for instance).

What could I do on the phone that would force it to kick back to full volume?  Something better than asking a friend to text me, or setting a 1 minute alarm, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I too have had this problem many times. (I have been told it is a known bug in iOS having to do with playing MP3 files that are shorter than two second.) The easiest way to get your phone back to normal volume is to pause the music (or audio/video, as the case may be) and then resume it. The volume should be back to normal after that.

Comment: So apparently 11 years later Apple still couldn’t fix their software! Still having the same issue, difference for me is pausing/ playing doesnt help it keeps being stuck! Ive had this now over multiple IOS versions and iPhones. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to try is just update the operating system on your iPhone 4 to 5.1.1. Perhaps Apple included a bug fix in one of the updates.
If you're already up to date (and accidentally typed 5.0.1) then I would try Reset All Settings.
Open Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset All Settings.

This will set any customized settings (preferences) to their defaults (and require you to re-enter wi-fi passwords) but does not delete any content from the phone.

If that doesn't do the trick you should try a Restore through iTunes or the Erase All Contents and Settings in the same screen previously described. Just make sure you are backed up (by syncing with iTune or setting up iCloud!)